# Field Calc Python/VB script to populate field with one field, along with the last 6 digits of another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to populate a field in a table using field calculator with the value of the field in another, concatenated with the last 6 digits of another field.Example below, I would like a field SUBZONE to be populated with the zone code U, along with the last 6 digits of objectID, so U123456

EG:

OBJID
000000006000123456

ZONE
U

output new field:

U123456

A script will make this so easy.

Comment: You will not need an advanced calculation. With the python (or python 9.3) parser: SUBZONE ='U' + str(!OBJECTID!)[-6:], this means the string 'U' and the last 6 digits of the OBJECTID converted to a string, joined with simple concatenation. It becomes a little tricky if OBJECTID isn't 6 digits long, use zfill then..

Comment: would this be correct fi SUBZONE is not always U?                 
SUBZONE = '!ZONE!' + str(!OBJECTID!)[-6:]

Comment: Yes, the SUBZONE is implied by your field calculator so you only need to enter the second half.. if your OBJECTID is less than 6 digits then use 'U' + str(!OBJECTID!).zfill(6)[-6:], zfill has no effect if the string is already 6 or more characters but will pad to the left 0's to make 6 characters then [-6:] instructs python to take the rightmost 6 characters of the string *only*. If your subzone is not always U then where do you get that from? if it comes from your Zone field then the calc is !Zone! + str(!OBJECTID!).zfill(6)[-6:].

Comment: Good to hear, I'll put that in as an answer to close this post off.

Answer (score 4):

Your field calculation will be `'U' + str(!OBJECTID!).zfill(6)[-6:]`. This has several components:

- using [str()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) we convert the value in OBJECTID to a string, this is required by the next step.
- [zfill()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_zfill.htm) the string with 0's to the left to make *at least 6 characters* using zfill(6), this has no effect if the string has 6 or more characters already.
- With the [indexing notation [-6:]](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) we extract the rightmost 6 digits, no matter how long the string is..

If your subzone is derived from a field then you can substitute that value using the calculation `!Zone! + str(!OBJECTID!).zfill(6)[-6:]` (assuming your subzone character comes from a field called Zone).